# What are Facebook "Quick Experiments"?

Tags: facebook

Today, a mysterious new nub popped up next to my facebook chat panels. It is called "Quick Experiments". When I click on it, a chat-sized view opens up: [image: My Quick Experiments].

Google tells me something about Facebook ad experiments, but I'm not sure if that is what this view is about. Especially since I haven't ever bought Facebook ads.

What are Facebook Quick Experiments?

Comment: Came here for the same thing. Just saw it pop up.

Comment: I don't have reputation to answer apparently. But it's a tool used for employees. They've obviously messed up the feature flag and launched it to non-employees as well.

It's for running experiments (AB tests, multivariate tests etc) quickly :)

Comment: https://launchdarkly.com/blog/the-billion-versions-of-facebook-youve-never-seen/ Can't answer due to low reputation, but this article explains it. It's used for quick in-prod tests. "so our tool is called Quick Experiment and it’s really used to launch experiments really quickly so developers don’t have to do… write too much code or worry about how to analyze these experiments and it works across the board, across all our platforms."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a Facebook glitch, where they accidentally released an internal tool that's usually used by Facebook staff to try out small code projects with small sections of the facebook user base, to all Facebook users.

They figured out the glitch and removed the tool a few hours after it first appeared.