# Are Facebook Quick Experiments An Exploit?

Tags: facebook, html, ios, headers

I logged in today and found this in the corner of the screen:

[image]

I used inspect element and did a quick search on the one of the class or components names (DuckDuckGo query for "fbQuickExperiments" and "fbQuickExperimentsN" and found the following on a [Github Page](https://github.com/subdiox/BlitzHeaders/blob/master/FBQuickExperiment.h):

[image]

Apparently the description in "About" page under the BlitzHeaders folder in the repository reads: "Disassembled header files of World of Tanks Blitz."

Comment: Here is a page elsewhere in the Githup repo, not sure if related but my iOS wasn't fully updated recently with the latest security fixes until an hour ago, so the probability increases.  

https://github.com/Siguza/v0rtex/blob/master/docs/index.md

Comment: see https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/144303/what-are-facebook-quick-experiments